# Implement s2s pixel

Tags: javascript

I have to implement s2s pixel in website and my pixel is as
.
I have to implement it using javascript and they send me also javascript code as

```
  function getParameterByName(name) {
   name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
       results = regex.exec(location.search);
   return results === null ? "" :           decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));


        }
     </script>
```

In my landing page there is download button when a user clicks on that pixel should be fired plz help me in this

Comment: What's the problem in particular?

Comment: Hin andrew plz help me i have give s2s pixel that is as <iframe src="http://mp.castplatform.com/api/mp/1/2611/1671?clk=pubid=5378&secure=1"
        width="0" height="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"
        style="border: 0;"></iframe> and i ahve take prameters it when user clicks on download button and use also above script code